# How much does the general public know of the series' events?

Tags: stranger-things

In *Stranger Things*, I'd like to have an overview of what the general public know of the events of the series and how it relates to the real events. This is in reference to a woman's remark on "all the terrible things that happen in Hawkins" at the meeting in S4E07.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

| Season | Public perception | What's behind it |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Barb disappears (declared dead in season 2). | Barb taken to upside-down by demogorgon and killed. |
|  | Will disappeared and later reappeared. | Kidnapped to upside-down (infested) and rescued. |
|  | Benny completes suicide. | Actually killed by government agents because he had extended contact with Eleven. |
|  | Students break into Hawkins middle school. | Eleven kills several government agents. |
| Two | Bob dies. | Bob killed by demogorgons helping the others to escape. |
|  | Experiments on children at Hakins Lab exposed, leading to closure of the lab. | The government wanted to weaponize psychic children. |
| Three | A mall fire killed several dozens of townspeople | The people where killed to form the mind flayer's body in the upside-up. |
|  | ...including Hopper | Hopper was transported to Russia while closing the gate. |
|  | ...and Billy | Billy sacrificed himself to kill the mind flayer's body. |
| Four | Three teenagers are brutally killed, it is pinned on Eddie. | Vecna killed them via psychic connection to open a huge gate. |
|  | Other students hide Eddie from the police. | Spot-on for once, but apparently only temporarily relevant. |
|  | An earthquake impacts Hawkins, killing over 20 people, including Jason and Eddie | Vecna opened a gate |
|  | ..., injuring Max | Vecna killed Max to complete the mega-gate (El later resurrected her). |

Comment: Don't forget Bennie's death in season 1.